# How do I make a relationship to a classless value in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy under Flask. I have a table that represents a mode my system can be in. I also have a table that contains lists of elevations that are applicable to each mode. (So this is a many-to-many relationship.) In the past when I've added an attribute (like `elevations` inside `ScanModes` here) to a class mapped to a table, the target was also a class.

Does it make more sense to wrap the elevations in a class (and make a corresponding table?) so I can use `relationship` to make `ScanModes.elevations` work, or should I use a [query-enabled property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#building-query-enabled-properties)? I'm also open to other suggestions.

```
elevation_mode_table = db.Table('elevation_mode', db.metadata,
                                db.Column('scan_mode', db.String,
                                          db.ForeignKey('scan_modes'),
                                          nullable=False),
                                db.Column('elevation', db.Float,
                                          nullable=False),
                                db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('scan_mode', 
                                                        'elevation'))

class ScanModes(db.Model):
    scan_mode = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    elevations = ?

    def __init__(self, scan_mode):
        self.scan_mode = scan_mode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the most straightforward approach would be to just map elevation_mode_table to a class:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
class ElevationMode(object):
    pass

mapper(ElevationMode, elevation_mode_table)

class ScanModes(db.Model):
    elevations = relationship(ElevationMode)
```

of course even easier is to just have ElevationMode be a declared class in the first place, if you need to deal with elevation_mode_table you'd get that from `ElevationMode.__table__` ...

The "query enabled property" idea here, sure you could do that too though you'd lose the caching benefits of relationship.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this in the morning. I really appreciate that you come on the site and give people support with the library!

Comment: I think this is not quite what I was looking for; maybe what I want isn't "SQLAlchemic" enough. I was imagining that the `elevations` attribute could just be an unwrapped list of values that were pulled from the `elevation_mode_table`. I guess the caching is done inside the `ElevationMode` object here, and that's why it's necessary?

Comment: Right now, I can achieve caching and my attribute as a list with your code (with `elevations` renamed to `_elevations`) plus making `elevations` be a property whose getter returns a list extracted from the `_elevations` attribute.

Comment: If you're looking for "elevations" to be a list of floats, then you can hit it with the association proxy: see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-scalar-collections